# product of two discrete sigma algebras need not be discrete

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I tried solving this problem but as X and Y are having discrete sigma algebra, then singletons are measurable. Henceforth, every singleton set in the product space is product of singleton sets from X and Y which means product space is also having discrete algebra. I don't know where I am going wrong.
All suggestions are invited

Comment: How do you define "having discrete sigma algebra"?  The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma-algebra#Simple_set-based_examples) defines it to mean the $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ is given by the power set of $X$.  Your notion of "singletons are measurable" seems a consequence rather than a definition, because singletons are measureable in (for example) Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

The product $X\times Y$ needs to be countable. If so, every subset of the product is a countable union of its singletons, which are mesurable as you pointed out, and is therefore mesurable. If neither $X$ nor $Y$ are countable, that may not be true. For example, with $X=Y=\mathbb{R}$, as it was said to me in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2238940/is-the-product-sigma-algebra-of-the-powerset-of-mathbbr-and-itself-equals-t), it is undecidable in ZFC.
[Here](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183530570) it is shown to be true for $X=Y=[0,1]$ using the Continuum Hypothesis.