# Is the product sigma-algebra of the powerset of $\mathbb{R}$ and itself equals to the powerset of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory

This question has already been asked on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/1obebh/is_the_product_sigma_algebra_of_the_powerset_of_r/), but didn't receive a satisfactory answer.

Comment: This is discussed in my [5 May 2002 sci.math.research post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=1691283) archived at Math Forum.

Comment: In his thesis, Kunen showed that this is undecidable in ZFC. In particular, he showed that this holds, e.g., under MA, and fails in the Cohen real model.

Comment: See also [https://mathoverflow.net/q/275375/](https://mathoverflow.net/q/275375/6085).